# Word input from one line in the textbox to another

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 5 text boxes marked with NX1, NX2, NX3 .... NX5.

I have a Textbox marked with Textbox2 that contains lines like:

```
2 4 6 8 11
1 2 3 4 12
3 4 7 9 13
4 5 7 9 14
```

Is there a possibility to enter the first word / number from TextBox2 Lines (0) in NX1? i.e. First Word (number 2 in NX1), (Second Word) number 4 in NX2, number 6 in NX3 and number 8 in NX4. and so on.

---

I tried this:

```
 Dim mytext As String
        Dim counter As Integer
        mytext = TextBox1.Text
        For counter = 1 To Len(TextBox1.Text)
            If Mid$(mytext, counter, 1) = " " Then
                GoTo NextPart
            End If
        Next counter
NextPart:
        MsgBox("'" + Mid$(mytext, 1, counter - 1) + "'")
        MsgBox("'" + Mid$(mytext, 2, counter - 1) + "'")
```

Comment: Don't tag your code as `vb.net` then use shit like `Len` `GoTo` `Mid$` and `MsgBox`. That is pre-NET code!

Answer (score 1):

Get the `TextBox.Lines(0)`. That's the first *line* of text. If the text parts are separated by a white space, just `Split()` the text (white space is the default separator).
If it's not, specify the separator: `Split("[SomeChar]"c)`.

You'll get 5 strings in a `String()` array. Assing `String(0)` to `NX1` etc.

```
Dim FirstLine As String = TextBox2.Lines(0)
Dim AllParts As String() = FirstLine.Split()
NX1.Text = AllParts(0)
NX2.Text = AllParts(1)
'(...)
```

Repeat the same procedure if you need the other text lines.

You could also use `LINQ` to perform the string assignments:

```
AllParts.Select(Function(s, i) Me.Controls("NX" & (i + 1)).Text = s).ToList()
```

Or, assemble everything in one expression:

```
TextBox2.Lines(0).Split().Select(Function(s, i) Me.Controls("NX" & (i + 1)).Text = s).ToList()
```

A description of this method:

```
[TextBox].Lines(0)    => Returns the first line of text in a TextBoxBase control
Split()               => Splits the text content using the default separator. 
                         Returns an array of String
Select((string, int)) => Selects each string returned by the Split() method and updates
                         the index of each iteration.
                         Performs an action: sets a control`s Text property.
ToList()              => Materializes the Enumerable collection returned by Select()
                         If omitted, in this case, the iteration is performed just once
```

`Me.Controls("NX" & (i + 1)).Text = s`:
Returns a `Form`'s Control which name is `"NX"` + a number and assigns a string to its Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split()` to split the string.

```
Dim columns = TextBox2.Lines(0).Split()
For i = 0 To columns.Length - 1
    Controls.Item("NX" & (i + 1)).Text = columns(i)
Next
```

The `Lines` property of the `TextBox` returns a string array containing the lines of the entered text.

`String.Split()` with no parameters splits a string at white spaces and returns a string array containing the parts (the columns of the first lines in this case).

The `Controls` property of the form returns a controls collection. The indexed `Item` property of the controls collection accepts either an `Integer` index or a control name as `String`.